# How to combine foreach loops in php

Tags: php, html

In trying to understand php and loop so Im creating an application that increases the saving by multiplying the rate each year. In the application the user puts in a set value and the rate from a radio button. After the submit button is clicked a table is shown that displays the the next ten years counted and the money saved each year until it hits ten years. Currently I have it show year one ten times, then two ten times until the table shows 10 years ten times. How do I fix my loops to display just ten years and the correct savings for each year.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="savings.php" method="POST">
        <?php
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
            echo'<p>Principle:<input type="text" id="Principle" name="Principle"></p>';
            echo'Interest Rate:<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="1"><label>1%</label>';
            //
            echo'<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="5"><label>5%</label>';
            //
            echo'<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="10"><label>10%</label>';
            //
            echo'<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>';
        }
        else{
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
                
            }
            else
            $Principle = (int)$_REQUEST["Principle"];
            $radioVal = $_POST["MyRadio"];
            echo'<table>';
            echo'<tr><th>Year</th>';
            echo'<th>Savings</th>';
            $Principle= $Principle + ($Principle * .05);
            foreach (range(1,10,1) as $Year){
                foreach (range(1,10,1) as $Rate){

                echo "<tr><td>$Year</td>
                <td>$$Principle</td></tr>";
            }
        }
            echo'</table>';
        }
            
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rate is monthly or yearly? And do you want to display the gross amount after each month or year? The first column name is "Month" which confuses me

Comment: Kien Nguyen Rate is yearly so in total it will only go up to ten years and I want to display the gross for each year so lets say year one total is 100 and the rate is 5% year two will be 105 (100+(100*.05) . For the second question that is my mistake it should be year not month

Answer (score 1):

1. Only 1 `for` loop is needed.
2. You are using the fixed value of `0.05` for calculating expression so it is not correct, it should be: `$Principle = $Principle + ($Principle * $radioVal / 100);`.
3. You have to put that expression inside the loop.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="savings.php" method="POST">
  <?php
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){
    echo'<p>Principle:<input type="text" id="Principle" name="Principle"></p>';
    echo'Interest Rate:<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="1"><label>1%</label>';
    //
    echo'<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="5"><label>5%</label>';
    //
    echo'<input type="radio" name="MyRadio" value="10"><label>10%</label>';
    //
    echo'<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>';
  }
  else{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET"){

    }
    else
    $Principle = (int)$_REQUEST["Principle"];
    $radioVal = $_POST["MyRadio"];
    echo'<table>';
    echo'<tr><th>Year</th>';
    echo'<th>Savings</th>';
    foreach (range(1,10,1) as $Year){
        $Principle = $Principle + ($Principle * $radioVal / 100);
        echo "<tr><td>$Year</td>
                <td>$$Principle</td></tr>";
    }
    echo'</table>';
  }

  ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```